# "what she said" VS "her saying"

Tags: grammar

> 1. We were all very disappointed about what she said.
> 2. We were all very disappointed about her saying that.

What's the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They are disappointed about the **things** that she **said**. The feeling is towards what was mentioned.
2. They are disappointed in **her** (for saying those things). The feeling is towards the person saying it.